# Wrong output from mktime() in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a php where that it sets the date up for the 1st September for each year. I am using CRON to state that everytime the date is 7th September, then the php will actually update the database for rows whose dates ae a week before that 7th September, (ist September).

Now the code below I tested for the 28th October and when I echo `$selectedDate` it outputs `2012-10-28` which is fine. But when I change the date to 1st September, it outputs `` `2011-12-01 `` which is obviously incorrect. it should output `2013-09-01 as the next September date will be in 2013. Then after the Ist September date has passed in 2013, then the year should change to 2014 and etc.

How can I get the correct date to be outputted?

Below is code:

```
$createDate = mktime(0,0,0,09,01,date("Y"));
$selectedDate =  date('Y-m-d', ($createDate));
```

Comment: Consider using `DateTime` objects to save yourself a world of pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `09` is interpreted as an **octal 9**, which is invalid.

It works as expected when you pass `9` instead of `09`:

```
$createDate = mktime(0,0,0,9,1,date("Y"));
//                         ^ ^  No preceeding 0s.
$selectedDate =  date('Y-m-d', ($createDate));

var_dump($createDate, $selectedDate);
```

Comment: @cbuckley: Very minor, very minor indeed. It's alright though :)